# Upside down orientation on iPhone 12 and iPhone 13

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, rotation, orientation

I have an iOS app which can rotate upside down on an iPhone 7 with iOS 15.6.
However the same app does not rotate upside down on an iPhone 13 or iPhone 12 with iOS 15.6.1.
Did Apple remove upside down orientation on newer devices or iOS versions?
If yes, is there maybe a list of all the devices which do not support upside down orientation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations) :

> Note:
> All iPadOS devices support the portraitUpsideDown orientation. It’s best practice to enable it for the iPad idiom. iOS devices without a Home button, such as iPhone 12, don’t support this orientation. You should disable it entirely for the iPhone idiom.

So you can’t upside down on iPhone 12