# iOS 16 Orientation .portraitUpsideDown not working

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, ios16

I have been working on an iOS app which uses CNC communications to move motors and so the iPhone in my app is mounted on the holder on a machine. Since it is held on a machine, the user views its iPhone device upside down.
My question is, my app was working very well in portrait upside down (The entire app including the launch screens, UIAlertViews and VC's) till I had updated it to the iOS 16. Now I am not getting the methods to get it back to the upside down mode.

Basically, I want the application to run upside down.

Kindly help

```
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portraitUpsideDown
}
```

[image]

Comment: Since your Info.plist only specifies upside down and you want the whole app to only support upside down then you shouldn't need any code anywhere that is related to orientation. The Info.plist setting should be all you need. BTW - where is the overridden `supportedInterfaceOrientations` that you posted in your question?

Comment: All those override has been written in iOS 16 to try out various methods. override i tried in ViewController.

Comment: The app still didn't turn upside down in iOS 16 with info.plist. It used to work in iOS 15 and below. Even the splash screens and alerts too were inverted. Not anymore with 16. Could you try it in your end and check if it works?

Comment: Did anyone got any chance to try out the upside down support only for iOS 16?

Comment: I just tried with a test app and two of my existing apps and my initial attempts failed to get them to support upside down portrait under iOS 16.2. Strange. I'll dig a bit deeper when I get a chance.

Comment: Just found this one: [Upside down orientation on iPhone 12 and iPhone 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73732726/upside-down-orientation-on-iphone-12-and-iphone-13)

Comment: I used to rotate the app upside down on all the devices till iPhone 13 before iOS 16 was installed. I made mistake by updating my device to iOS 16 after which it stopped the upside down orientation.